# Ошибки при подключении БД VS C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-localdb

я студент, препод дал задание "Сделать все как в методичке", а именно:

Сделать интерфейс, создать бд и 4 таблицы.
Код он так же предоставил, но не получается подключиться к БД. Постоянно ошибки какие-то лезут. Гугл помог решить 2-3 ошибки, теперь я конкретно завис и решил сам написать на форум.

Текущая ошибка:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server не существует, или доступ запрещен."

Вот мой код с которым возникают проблемы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
 
namespace LibraryApp
{
    public partial class FMain : Form
    {
        
 
        public FMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Conn(ConnectionString ,Book, dataGridView1);
        }
 
        public void Conn(string CS, string cmdT, DataGridView dgv)
        {
 
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdT, CS);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Table"); //ошибку выдает на этой строке
            dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table"].DefaultView;
        }
 
//Подозреваю, что ошибка где-то здесь. 
        private readonly string ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/Игорь/Desktop/Лукин ПРИЗ-312/Лукин ПРИЗ-312/С#/SQLServer/LibraryApp/LibraryApp/bin/Debug/dbLibrary.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI";
        //private readonly string ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "/dbLibrary.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI";
//==================
 
 
        private readonly string Book = "SELECT Book.IdBook AS ID,Genre.nameG AS Жанр, Book.nameB AS Название, Book.Author AS Автор," +
            "Book.Publisher AS Издательство, Book.YearOfPub AS[Год издания] " +
            "FROM Book INNER JOIN Genre ON Book.IdGenre=Genre.IdGenre";
 
        //C:\\Users\\Игорь\\Desktop\\Лукин ПРИЗ-312\\Лукин ПРИЗ-312\\С#\\SQLServer\\LibraryApp\\LibraryApp\\bin\\Debug/dbLibrary.mdf
 
 
        private void FMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblDate.Text = "Сегодня " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            lblTime.Text = "Время мск " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
 
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Text = "Время мск " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            timer1.Start();
        }
 
       
    }
}
```

Если нужно, могу прикрепить методичку с заданием.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь

Comment: Ну как минимум для начала убрать русские буквы к файлу базы. Это правило на всю жизнь. Ничего на кириллице. Ну и коннекшин  нужно открыть.

Comment: @Manul74 - DataAdapter сам откроет и закроет соединение, если ему передаётся просто строка соединения

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , Как тогда решить мою проблему? Ошибка возможно в пути к базе?

Comment: Какую именно РСУБД используете: Sql Server или MySql? Чес слово, задрали уже путать их! Это совершенно разные БД! Когда это выясним, можно будет двигаться дальше.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Не знаю... Я просто по методичке делал... Написано что Для работы с локальной бд VisualStudio предлагает встроенную СУБД SQL Server Express LocalDB. Видимо ее и использую)

Comment: Тогда поменяйте метку `mysql` на правильную

Comment: Да что ж такое-то... Express и LocalDB - это разные версии Sql Server, а не одно название.

Comment: Работаете в Visual Studio? В заголовке вижу VS. Или какую-то другую IDE используете?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Visual использую. Я вообще только начал в ней разбираться. По поводу названия в методичке так и написано... Для работы с локальной бд VisualStudio предлагает встроенную СУБД SQL Server Express LocalDB. Качество образования... Препод скачал методичку, сам не проверил рабочее или нет. Могу скинуть ссылку, посмотрите как там написано, если интересно

Comment: Хорошо. Раз используете VS, значит вместе с ней была установлена версия Sql Server LocalDB.

Comment: [Connection String Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) - здесь смотрите синтаксис строк соединения

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Увы не понимаю о чем там пишут. Попробую еще погуглить

Comment: Для начала, откажитесь от OLE. Это провайдер данных несколько устарел. Используйте типы без префикса `OleDb`. Такие как: `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlConnection` и т. п.